# How do I get first value instantly if my throttle is set to 120000

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, throttling

So basically I wan't to get data from server at start and then update it every 2 minutes, but instead it gets first value only after 2 minutes, what can I do about this?

Here is my js markup:

```
var itemViewModel = {
    item: ko.observable().extend({ throttle: 120000 }),
    loadcontent: function (getID) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/item/details/' + getID,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                itemViewModel.item(data);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Maybe this will help, here is a HTML markup:

```
<div id="item-details-content">
    <input type="hidden" id="item-id" value="@id" data-bind=""/>
    <div class="item-list" data-bind="init: itemPage.loadcontent(@id), with: itemPage.item">
```

### Conditions

1. There need to be and initial call of `loadcontent`
2. Everything must be inside `viewModel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not what the [`throttle extender`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/throttle-extender.html) ([link](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/throttle-extender.html)) is meant for. Use [`setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) ([link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)) instead.

`throttle` is meant to handle a scenario where you may receive an arbitrary amount of events in a short timespan and you do not want to act upon every single event. E.g. you have a search field with *autocomplete* functionality that uses a REST-API. You do not want to call the REST-API every single time a user pushes a key. Rather, you'd like to wait a bit until the user is done typing. This is a perfect use case for `throttle`.

What you are looking for is a way to repeat an action on a predetermined interval. JavaScript has a builtin function just for that and it's called `setInterval`.

```
var itemViewModel = {
    item: ko.observable().extend({ throttle: 120000 }),
    loadcontent: function (getID) {
        var loadData = function()
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/api/item/details/' + getID,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    itemViewModel.item(data);
                }
            });
        }
        loadData(); // initial call
        setInterval(loadData, 120000); // repeat every 2 minutes
    }
};
```

Comment: Cool but how I can apply to my solution?

Comment: Can you implement it into my code, because when I set ajax call into setInterval it gets data only after 2 mins.

Comment: Oh yes sure. Move your repeating code to a new function, in my example called 'foo'. Then call foo once at initialization and then setup an interval.

Comment: Don't confuse throttling with debouncing.

Comment: No, no I need it to be inside viewModel, because my data-bind sends `getID` to the function witch is essential, and that viewModel is called only when the appropriate page is loaded, so basically if I put this function outside of viewModel it will execute function even if I don't wan't it to. So yeah I need sa solution witch will be inside the viewModel.

Comment: Could give us a bit more detail about it is you are trying to accomplish? I've edited my answer to incorporate your code, but I'm not sure if this actually fits your problem...

Comment: I want it to load data from server, and then reload it every 2 minutes. Your given solution crashes the browser. Thing is the `getID` I get when my MVC is creating the page. And in future I want to create to objects of viewModel and set to elements side by side and update them individually. The code stops the page responsiveness for those milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Throttle's intended use is to make sure the function does not execute more then once every x seconds. As Martin said, setInterval would be better in this situation

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
     ko.observable();
}, 120000);

ko.observable();
```

Comment: I don't know how to implement this into my solution, can you help me understand this?